# Does exe4j version 4.2 support for openjdk 11?

Tags: java, exe4j

Does exe4j 4.2 support with openjdk 11 ?
Previously i was using exe4j 4.2 licensed version with java 1.6 and it worked fine but when we have migrated from java 1.6 to openjdk 11.0.1

Created exe's from exe4j is not working.

do we have any release notes for exe4j 4.2 and from which version of exe4j we can work with openjdk 11.0.1

Comment: "not working" - in what way?

Comment: ant 1.9.6 build is failing when exe4j tried to create exe from jar

Comment: What's the error?  It might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need exe4j 6.x+ for Java 9+.